# Cannot open map-reduce output url

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, ambari

I am newbie to Hadoop and learning from Big Data University. I am using 'my.imdemocloud.com' for practice. And running MR in putty.
After running the MR successfully one of the line is showing:

17/04/16 01:33:33 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://iop-bi-master.imdemocloud.com:8088/proxy/application_1489162640487_1985/

But the problem is when I am trying to open the link, the site is NOT opening with the message: 'This site can’t be reached'.

Please comment on this. Also I am unable to understand the Ambari Console and how to use it. Can anybody help me on this? url: 'https://ambari.datascientistworkbench.com/#/main/dashboard/metrics'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below Link

**https://iop-bi-master.imdemocloud.com:8443/gateway/yarnui/yarn/apps/RUNNING**

Here you can find the Running Applications.

Now Select your application_id from here & you can track your application.

In Ambari Console  if you want to view Namenode,Resource Manager... Related Gui, there is quick link option.

if you want resourcemanager ui:
  select Yarn from left menu and use quick links option and select needed link.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows or Windows Parallels, try changing your security settings. Go to ***Settings/Update & Security/For Developers/Remote Desktop/Allow remote connections to this computer***. 
You should be able to establish a connection after that.